# Why do I get 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: c, openssl

Why does this code result in 301 error when trying to access sites that has a `.net` suffix

```
void test(const char * host, const char *index)
{
    BIO *bio, *out;
    SSL_CTX * ctx;
    SSL * ssl;
    int len;
    char tmpbuf[1024];
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    char ready[1204];
    char format[] = "%s:http";
    sprintf(ready, format , host);
    char req_template[] =  "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
    char ready_request[1024];
    sprintf(ready_request , req_template , index, host);
    const SSL_METHOD * method = SSLv23_client_method(); 
    if (!method)
        exit(-1);
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if (!ctx)
        exit(-1);
    if (!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,"/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt","/etc/ssl/certs/"))
    {
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
        exit(-1);
    }
    bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx); 
    BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
    SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
    char temp[1024];
    sprintf(temp, "%s:https",host);
    if (BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, temp) < 0)
    {
        memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
        sprintf(temp, "%s:http", host);
        bio = BIO_new_connect(temp);
        if (BIO_do_connect(bio) < 0 )
        {
            BIO_free_all(bio);
            SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
            exit(-1);
        }       
    }
    printf("###\n%s\n###\n",ready_request);
    out = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    if(BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0) 
        exit(-1);

    BIO_puts(bio,ready_request);
    for(;;) 
    {
        len = BIO_read(bio, tmpbuf, 1024);
        if(len <= 0) break;
        BIO_write(out, tmpbuf, len);
    }
    BIO_free(bio);
    BIO_free(out);
}
int main()
{

    test("openssl.org", "/docs/manpages.html");
    test("pastebin.com", "/raw/j0BnRwBw");
    test("pastebin.com", "/j0BnRwBw");

}
```

for some reason that i can't figure out the first time `test` is called it returns a 301 status code but the two time test is called it returns the html code or the paste code with out any problems

Does this have anything to do with the fact that the websites use different technologies or  if they have some sort of firewall, I believe pastebin uses cloudflare to protect it self, I also tried using `User-Agent` but still got the same result

Comment: The 301 is happening on the server side of the `.net` site ... It is saying that the page you are trying to access has moved.  This could simply be because the server moves you from `example.net` to `www.example.net` -- Or something like `http` -> `https`  Either way there probably is a "follow redirects" directive for your code, so that it doesn't "return" the redirect .. It will "follow" it ..

Comment: @Zak how do i deal with it in openssl ? can you show simple code or provide more information on how to follow the redirects

Comment: You extract the url from the location header, then access that new url

Comment: @AllanWind but the location header has the same url as the one i am trying to access

Comment: Please include the relevant headers next time (openssl/err.h, openssl/ssl.h, and string.h), and it's useful to tell us how you link the program (`gcc your_program.c -lcrypto -lssl`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `www.` as a prefix to the host header and for `BIO_set_conn_hostname` you should use the format `www.<hostname>.com:https` or  `www.<host>.org:http` for `BIO_new_connect`

for some reason, the [docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/BIO_set_conn_hostname.html) do not mention this

```
void test(const char * host, const char *index)
{
    BIO *bio, *out;
    SSL_CTX * ctx;
    SSL * ssl;
    int len;
    char tmpbuf[1024];
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    char req_template[] =  "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.%s\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
    char ready_request[1024];
    sprintf(ready_request , req_template , index, host);
    const SSL_METHOD * method = SSLv23_client_method(); 
    if (!method)
        exit(-1);
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if (!ctx)
        exit(-1);
    if (!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,"/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt","/etc/ssl/certs/"))
    {
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
        exit(-1);
    }
    bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx); 
    BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
    SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
    char temp[1024];
    sprintf(temp, "www.%s:https",host);
    if (BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, temp) < 0)
    {
        memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
        sprintf(temp, "www.%s:http", host);
        bio = BIO_new_connect(temp);
        if (BIO_do_connect(bio) < 0 )
        {
            BIO_free_all(bio);
            SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
            exit(-1);
        }       
    }
    printf("###\n%s\n###\n",ready_request);
    out = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    if(BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0) 
        exit(-1);

    BIO_puts(bio,ready_request);
    for(;;) 
    {
        len = BIO_read(bio, tmpbuf, 1024);
        if(len <= 0) break;
        BIO_write(out, tmpbuf, len);
    }
    BIO_free(bio);
    BIO_free(out);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first request `https://openssl.org/docs/manpages.html` returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
...
Location: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manpages.html
...
```

You make another request to that url.  To demonstrate it working, I changed your first test case to read:

```
test("www.openssl.org", "/docs/manpages.html");
//    ^^^^
```

and the server now returns the response you were expecting:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

Comment: if i make the request with `www.openssl.org` then i does not redirect but this approach does not work with pastebin is there a unified way to access both sites without making more than one request

Comment: Yes, use the url that the server expects in the first request.  I was not able to reproduce the issue with the two pastebin.com test cases.

Comment: this would require me to remember the url for each website and if i should use `www.` with a certain website or not

Comment: How is that different from remembering the urls you use now?  A given url may  change urls on you at any time so you probably want to implement the code to follow redirects.